# How does this code that toggles a boolean work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have some code following a tutorial that works fine, but I can't understand why. The code is to make a simple 2D character flip from left to right based on the direction it's going.

```
private bool facingright;

void Start () {
    //defaults that we are in fact facing right when game starts.
    facingright = true;
```

Clearly it just states that the bool is true when the game starts. We then create an additional method to control when it is true or not true:

```
private void Flip(float horizontal){
    //if horizontal is greater than 0 and not facing right. 
    //or if horizontal is less than zero and is facing right
    if (horizontal > 0 && !facingright || horizontal < 0 && facingright) {
        //you are no longer facing right, but how does it go back?
        facingright = !facingright;

        //theScale is transforming the x axis on scale.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        //the value of the axis change is  x * -1
        theScale.x *= -1;
        //Then change the new value to theScale?
        transform.localScale = theScale;
```

So, I can't for the life of me wrap my head around why this If statement works.You can see in comments i understand that it activates if this happens or something else happens. From MY understanding, this would ONLY then make facingright = !facingright - but how does it then come back to !facingright = facing right ?

Is it saying that facingright = !facingright, but if this is already true, then reverse it?

At the same time, the scaling moves the x axis to 1 or -1. The code though only requests to do it once. How does it also revert the changes? Any assistance in understanding this would be greatly appreciated. I think this is all the code related to this piece.

Comment: I think maybe you're getting qualifiers and assignments confused. Also, 1 *-1 = -1. However, -1 * -1 = 1. That's how it flips.

Comment: "not true" is false. "not false" is true.

Comment: Thanks guys! So the scaling is actually flipping it? After each time it flips, the scaling reverse that flip making it loop, or? Blah.

Comment: Another way to do it is: `facingright = horizontal > 0;` (which means if horizontal is greater than zero, then facing right it true, otherwise it's false).

Answer (score 3):

To understand the code, you first need to understand what you're trying to achieve. Specifically:

- If the character's `horizontal` movement value is positive, the character is moving to the right side of the screen. In that case, you want the character facing right. I.e. you want the `facingright` value to be `true`. Conversely, if the value is negative, you want to be facing left, and the `facingright` value to be `false`.
- If the `horizontal` value is positive and `facingright` is *not* `true` (i.e. it's `false`), or the `horizontal` value is negative and `facingright` *is* `true`, then we need to do something about that. Otherwise, not.

It is also helpful to understand the order of precedence for the `&&` and `||` operators. In particular, the `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`.

So, the expression in the `if` statement — `horizontal > 0 && !facingright || horizontal < 0 && facingright` — is translating the second bullet point above into code. You can read it more properly as `(horizontal > 0 && !facingright) || (horizontal < 0 && facingright)`, which is the essence of the bullet point. Check to see if the movement value matches the "facing right" value, and if they don't match, do something about it.

So, what to do about it? Well, the first thing is to invert the `facingright` value. That's what `facingright = !facingright;` does. This fixes the flag so it matches the direction of movement.

The next thing to do is to actually adjust the direction the character is facing. In the code you posted, this is done simply by flipping the transform for the character. Negating the `x` component of the scaling vector retrieved from the transform has this effect. It causes the character's coordinate space to be reversed relative to the world coordinate space, which in turn causes the character to be drawn as a sort of mirror-image of its normal appearance, i.e. flipped about the vertical axis.

Note that the statement `theScale.x *= -1;` is equivalent to `theScale.x = theScale.x * -1;`. So if the value of `x` is `1`, the new value is `-1`, and if the value is already `-1`, it gets set back to `1`.

And of course, all that code gets executed only when the `facingright` value is not in sync with the actual direction of movement.

For what it's worth, I do find this code a bit fragile. It is my preference to not rely on state variables that need to be in sync with each other. It would have been relatively simple here for the code to simply note when the movement value changes from a positive to negative value or vice a versa, and update the transform to the absolute positive or negative value that corresponds to the movement direction, rather than always negating both a flag and the transform scale's `x` value. But that's certainly a subjective assessment of the code. There's nothing wrong per se with the code you have now.

Comment: I was going to fire off an answer. You beat me to it; and although in such scenarios I usually just make my answer better than the rest (IMO) and post it anyways; in this case, sincerely, I couldn't possibly do any better. +1.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed explanations. I will be going over it a few more times when I get to work because there is explanations here that were not given during these tutorials, but now I atleast understand that the facingright is inverted with that one string of code. 

Would you be willing to post how you would personally change the direction versus calling the flag each time? I feel like it's clunky as well when going over it and would be very thankful :)

Comment: @LocalNerd: given a value for `facingright`, you can assign directly to the scale, as e.g. transform.localScale = new Vector3(facingright ? 1 : -1, 1, 1);`. There are other options where, for example, you keep a "previous horizontal value" instead of the "facing right" value and execute the flip logic when the sign of the horizontal value changes. It's a bit beyond the scope of a standard Stack Overflow Q&A to try to enumerate all the possible ways to approach the problem, especially since the code you have is basically working.